ubuntu 22.04 LTS removed all files folders application suddenly
I recently purchased (around 3 months back) Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed some software like VLC, VS code, chrome browser, Jupyter for coding. 2 days back I started laptop and I saw everything is wiped. No folders, no files, no software, even I created a user for my son is also removed.
Should I keep antivirus on Ubuntu? If yes, please suggest better antivirus software?
Is there any auto reset settings by default enabled on ubuntu?
Any chance to recover the deleted files/folder?

Anti Virus not needed. No auto settings of any kind. Sorry gone is gone. You may want to take it for repair, something happened to it and it was no Ubuntu that did this.

You've given few details as to what you actually purchased; eg. was this is a new laptop on which Ubuntu was pre-installed; or a refurbished laptop on which Ubuntu was installed; etc...   Was Ubuntu installed? or was it running as a live environment (ie. everything is gone once turned off; and you'd not turned it off before maybe?)  If pre-installed (inc. refurbished) they often come with a restore to new device tool, which if run will make it appear as if its new, and the mistake was mistakenly or in error running that tool. Getting your data back from your backups will be your best bet

"even I created a user for my son is also removed" normal or sudo user? if sudo son possibly nuked the system.

"Any chance to recover the deleted files/folder" did you even make a backup? Rather than install anti-virus, install and use something like Timeshift

This question is similar to: Do I need to have antivirus software installed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
